# Symfony2 Doctrine form submit validation failed, always update entity

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

For couple of hours im trying to resolve an issue with submiting Symfony2 form over Doctrine 2 Entity object.

I'm using custom ObjectManagerFlusher, registred as service under kernel request.

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Namespace\CustomBundle\Services;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class ObjectManagerFlusher
{

    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function flush()
    {
        if ($this->entityManager->isOpen()) {
            $this->entityManager->flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Simply, this service should on every kernel terminate request proceed with flush on every persisted entity.

The main issue is, when i do submit SF2 form (example below), then i do call method **isValid** to call validators, do all necesary things etc. **but** problem exists only when i do edit existing DB records mapped to entities, completly new ones are validated fine, as they should.

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $this->logger->save('example log');
    return true;
}
```

I cannot do validation things on presented ObjectManagerFlusher presented above, because of custom validation groups.

So the questions are:

1) If there's any kind of better solution to flush "all in once" entities, similar to presented method, but only ones that are valid?

2) If there's not better way to do so, how to solve that issue?

Many thanks for every support

Comment: I don't understand the question.  When an entity form is posted the entity will get updated with the posted values.  Even if the validation fails, the entity is still updated.  If you flush the entity manager then the changed values will still end up in the database even though they are invalid.  Doctrine 2 knows nothing about validation.  Your flusher is not really going to be of much use.  Do the flushing in your controller after verifying the data is valid.

Answer (score 1):

If you map an entity to a form, every time you call handleRequest, it will bind the form's contents to the entity. There no stopping this as it is completely expected functionality.

One way to work with this is to have form models, which are non db mapped entities that exist only to be mapped to a form.  And then once a form is valid you copy the fields from the model into your database entity.

Comment: someone covered this nicely in https://blog.martinhujer.cz/symfony-forms-with-request-objects/